# When is the convolution of two sequences equidistributed?

Tags: number-theory, ergodic-theory, equidistribution

A sequence of integers $(x_n)$ is *equidistributed* mod $p$ if for all $a$ mod $p$,  we have as $n \to \infty$:
$$ \dfrac{1}{X} \# \{n < X: x_n \equiv a \mod p \} \to \dfrac{1}{p}.$$

Let $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ be two integer sequences. Define the *convolution* of $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ to be the sequence $(a_n \star b_n)$, where:
$$ a_n \star b_n = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k b_{n-k}.$$

What are sufficient conditions we can impose on the sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ that ensure that $(a_n \star b_n)$ is equidistributed mod $p$?